# Integrating with MAM software

Tags: architecture, integration

I have been hired to fix a software problem that is not allowing the business to work efficiently with their ERP system. They are currently using MAM software but the problem is that whenever they change the price of an item on the server it does not change on the website even after syncing it up and refreshing. I'm curious to know why it is doing this as I believe that the problem is that when integrating the software something got mislabeled and the node doesn't know where to point. Would really appreciate some help or guidance. Thanks Guys

we have tried scoping through the code but to no avail. Maybe as were not experienced enough we couldn't spot the problem but someone else might know straight away.